# If $P=(x_0,y_0)$ is a point in a focal chord of the parabola $x^2=4py$ then find the coordinates of the other point

Tags: analytic-geometry

$\textbf{Exercise:}$

If $\overline{PQ}$ is a focal chord of the parabola $x^2=4py$ and the coordinates of $P$ are $(x_0,y_0)$, show that the coordinates of $Q$ are
$$
\left(\frac{-4p^2}{x_0},\frac{p^2}{y_0}\right)
$$
([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUrBz.png))

$\textbf{Remainder:}$

A focal chord is the line segment from one point in the parabola to another one in the parabola passing through the focus.

$\textbf{My try:}$

[image]

My idea was to use the coordinates of the point $P=(x_0,y_0)$ and the focus $(0,p)$ to determine the equation of that line. Then I would proceed by considering the solutions to that equation and $x^2=4py$ to get the points of intersection. So let's calculate:

$$\textbf{Important things to note: }\boxed{y=mx+p}\boxed{\color{blue}{\text{distance in blue}=-x_0}}\boxed{\color{red}{\text{distance in red}=p-y_0}}$$

$$m=\frac{p-y_0}{-x_0}\implies \boxed{y=(\frac{y_0-p}{x_0})x+p}$$
Since we're looking for points of intersection and since the equation of the parabola can be written as $y=x^2/4p$ then: $$x^2/4p=(\frac{y_0-p}{x_0})x+p$$
Using the quadratic equation after simplifications we will get $$x=\frac{(4py_0-4p^2)\pm\sqrt{(4p^2-4py_0)-4x_0(-4p^2)}}{2x_0}$$
but that's not the result I'm looking for.

May someone show me where I got wrong in my reasoning, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus of $x^2=4py$ is at $(0,p)$. Therefore, the focal line with slope $m$ is
$$
y=mx+p\tag{1}
$$
$x$ for the two points of intersection with the parabola satisfy
$$
x^2=4p(mx+p)\implies x^2-4pmx-4p^2=0\tag{2}
$$
Using [Vieta's Formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we get that the product of the two roots of $(2)$ is
$$
x_0x_1=-4p^2\tag{3}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
x_0^2x_1^2=16p^2y_0y_1\tag{4}
$$
Thus, the product of the two $y$ values is
$$
y_0y_1=\frac{x_0^2x_1^2}{16p^2}=\frac{\left(-4p^2\right)^2}{16p^2}=p^2\tag{5}
$$
Therefore, if $(x_0,y_0)$ is one end of the focal chord, the other end would be
$$
(x_1,y_1)=\left(\frac{-4p^2}{x_0},\frac{p^2}{y_0}\right)\tag{6}
$$

Comment: Ah! You used Vieta's rule?

Comment: @user168559: I have added some more explanation.

Comment: Much clearer thanks boss you're the best!